# Pascal - Write all divisors of a number and sum them up

Tags: pascal

I just started programming and we were given the assignment in the title. I have no idea how to get those numbers in a summable form, so I thought that i will at least write them out, but for some reason i can't see, it doesn't work. Any advice?

```
  var
      a,i: integer;
      del: array [1..32767] of boolean;
  begin
      i:=1;
      readln(a);
      for i:=1 to 32767 do del[i]:=false;
      while i<>a do
      begin
          for i:=1 to 32767 do
              begin
              if (a MOD i =0) then del[i]:=true;
              end
      end;
      if del[i] then writeln(i,' je delitelem ',a);
  end.
```

Please consider that I am a total newb, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path, but you don't actually even need to store the divisors - just output each one as it is found ( mod = 0 ) and add its value to an accumulator variable.

And then you also don't need the `while`. Instead, change your `for` loop to only go up to `a` instead of 32767.

Comment: I actually need to write them out, since then I need to tell if  "a"  is a number with a whole square and cubic root. And i hadn!t quite gotten to how to solve that :D

Also, is there a way to make an array from 1 to theoretical infinity, without using the biggest number possible for integers?